# Geocoding your location found android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, gps, geocoding

My code currently displays the users location on a map... using the code below

```
private void initMyLocation() {
    final MyLocationOverlay overlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, map);
    overlay.enableMyLocation();

    overlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            controller.setZoom(8);
            controller.animateTo(overlay.getMyLocation());
        }
    });
    map.getOverlays().add(overlay);
}
```

I want to use the current location of the user and perform geocding on it to display the address as a toast message.. Would i have to delete the code above and retrieve the location by separate longitude and latitude values? Preferably i wouldnt want to go changing the code above as it already works.. I can't seem to find any good tutorials out there.. Could someone please direct me to one?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Since `MyLocationOverlay` already implements `LocationListener`, you could simply subclass it and override the `onLocationChanged` listener method and perform your geocoding there (preferably in a new thread/async task to avoid blocking the overlay processing!).

   Something like:

   ```
   private void initMyLocation() {
       final MyLocationOverlay overlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, map){
           public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location location)
           {
               //subclass AsyncTask to take a location parameter for 
               //doInBackground where it geocodes and then passes a String
               //to onPostExecute where you can display a toast
               new MyAsyncTask().execute(location);

               //remember to call the parent implementation to avoid breaking
               //MyLocationOverlay default functionality
               super.onLocationChanged(location);
           }
       };
       overlay.enableMyLocation();

       overlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               controller.setZoom(8);
               controller.animateTo(overlay.getMyLocation());
           }
       });
       map.getOverlays().add(overlay);
   }
   ```
2. The other option might be to write a custom `LocationListener` and register for updates for location and do pretty much the same thing as in the code above. IMO, this is probably redundant and unnecessarily expensive since, as explained above, you already have a `LocationListener` implementation to hook into so why write another?

Comment: @ no.good.at.coding Thank you..It appears with an error... 'MyAsyncTask cannot be resolved to a type'.. so do i create a new class to perform the geocoding - 'MyAsyncTask' class ?? Any tutorials i have found for geocoding have used the longitude and latitude.. so can i just pass my location variable for geocoding? Sorry im very new to android..

Comment: @IrishGal Yes, if you see the comments in the snippet, I mention that you should 'subclass AsyncTask'. So you should create a new class that extends [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) where you should write the geocoding code there. The reason for using the AsyncTask (or any other technique where a new thread will be spawned) is because geocoding will likely be an expensive operation involving network I/O which would block the operation of `MyLocationOverlay` since we're initiating it from within that class.

Comment: Also, the [`Location`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) object has `getLatitude()` and `getLongitude()` methods which will give you the latitude and longitude values encapsulated by that object.